# HBase map/reduce dependency issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, resteasy, hadoop2

1. Overview

---

I developed a Rest api service based on resteasy framework. In the service, i will store data to HBase database. then, execute map/reduce process trigged by some condition(e.g. insert one record).

2. Requires

---

In the Map class, i import some third part libraries. i do not want to package those libraries to the war file.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(HBaseInitializer.TABLE_DATA,   // input HBase table name
                                          scan,                      // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
                                          LuceneMapper.class,        // mapper
                                          null,                      // mapper output key
                                          null,                      // mapper output value 
                                          job);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://master:9000/qin/luceneFile"));
job.submit();
```

3. Problem

---

If package all libraries in the war file which will be deploy to jetty container, it work well. if not package third part library to the war,but upload those library to hdfs and add them to class path,  it does not work.  like below

```
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://master:9000"); 
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); 
Path classpathFilesDir = new Path("bjlibs"); 
FileStatus[] jarFiles = hdfs.listStatus(classpathFilesDir); 
for (FileStatus fs : jarFiles) { 
      Path disqualified = new Path(fs.getPath().toUri().getPath()); 
      DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(disqualified, conf);
}
hdfs.close();
```

Comment: Are you submitting MapReduce job from the host that is running Jetty?

Comment: yes. the jetty instance is separated with the hadoop clsuter. i.e in different network

Comment: you can also look at distributed cache  concept.https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/hadoop-add-third-party-libraries-to-mapreduce-job/

Comment: when submit the job, it will find some jar file(like hdfs://tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-war.dir/webapp/lib/netty-3.3.6.jar) , it does not find it. because it located in local file system (e.g. file://tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-war.dir/webapp/lib/netty-3.3.6.jar).

Comment: in your blog, you run the mapreduce by hadoop tool. but in my scenario i submit job remotely

Comment: @sravan did you test the distributed cache in hbase mapreduce that submitted by web app?

Answer (score 0):

try TableMapReduceUtil.addHBaseDependencyJars()